# Why "was" not "were" in "Nearly £20 was taken from my bank account"

Tags: plural-forms, singular, measure-expressions

I've always said "$100 were taken" not "$100 was taken" because I thought $100 is plural. Could you explain why "was" not "were"? Any other helpful notes about the issue would be appreciated.

> Nearly £20 was taken from my bank account

Comment: It's because $100 and $20 are both being thought of as ***a** [single] sum of money*, not a collection consisting of several individual dollars.

Comment: Yes, FumbleFingers got it--what's being taken is **money**, a non-count item.

Comment: The was I'd think of the difference is `100 $1 bills were taken from me` vs `1 $100 bill was taken from me`

Comment: Google [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams) suggests "dollars were" v. "dollars was" is difficult for native speakers, too. However, many of the "dollars was" instances are from sentences like "A premium of ten dollars was awarded...," in which the verb agrees with another word than "dollars." I think the rule-makers are inventing reasons for what has become colloquial. Numbers, more and more, have become singular in construction. "Four people are a good number for dinner"; but "Four is a good number for dinner." We can blame the math teachers: Even "Two and two is four" is quite common.

Comment: “Two and two is four” is common because the verb "to be" doubles as the copula in English. Other languages, like Japanese, for example would say 「2と2は4です」with `desu` being the copula at the end. A good way to think about the copula is it being the equal sign.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Because phrases that indicate *the amount of* sum, time, distance, weight, temperature, etc. are treated as singular:

> 10 million pounds **is** a lot of money.

= This sum is a lot of of money.

> 50 liters of petrol **fills** my car.

= This quantity fills my car.

> Five kilometers **is** a long way to walk.

= This distance is a long way to walk.

> Fifty degrees **is** a very high temperature.

= This temperature is a very high temperature.

And so on.

Comment: Thank you. It was confirmed in Practical English Usage, section 527.1, Plural expression with singular verbs.

Comment: However, if you were indicating the number of $1 coins that were taken from your wallet, you would say that 20 $1 coins were taken.

Comment: This sum is a lot of _of_ money

Answer (score 5):

If a box had contained twenty one-dollar bills, then one might say "twenty dollars were taken from the box" [note that the above might possibly written as "20 dollars", but not as "$20"].  If the box had contained a single twenty-dollar bill, however, the verb should clearly be singular.  Further, unless the taking consisted entirely of one-dollar bills, the only significance of the number "twenty" would as a description of a single value.  The notation "$20" doesn't generally mean twenty individual dollars, but instead is shorthand for "a quantity of money with the same value as twenty individual dollars".  Since any verb would bind to "quantity", rather than the dollars which would have the same value, the verb should be singular.

Comment: "*If the box had contained a single twenty-dollar bill, however, the verb should clearly be plural*." = you mean clearly be singular, don't you?
Nice comment by the way.

Answer (score -1):

> Nearly £20 was taken from my bank account

While 100 dollars is plural so you naturally say were.  But twenty quid was taken.  Wiki - The word Quid was also used in connection to multiple pounds

You could also say 20 clams were taken or 20 of my finest bills were taken.  But it would be a score was taken.  Similarly twenty bob, nicker, wedge or wonga would be was.  But 20 smackeroos were taken.