# Here is / are fifty bucks

Tags: singular-vs-plural, subject-verb-agreement

In a series I'm watching at the moment, someone said 'Here is fifty bucks.'

I would've guessed that it is called 'Here are 50 bucks'.

Is the sentence above correct? If so, why?

Comment: The answers to this question might be helpful: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/34412/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Short answer

Grammatically, it's incorrect, but...

### But...

In everyday conversation, money amounts (among other plural things) are often treated as singular. Personally, I think it's because it takes a lot more effort to say, "Here are" than to say, "Here is" or "Here's". And this incorrect grammar so commonly used that many people, including myself, don't even blink an eye when it's used.

"Here are", when spoken quickly, becomes "Here're", so many people I think say to themselves "whatever, I'll just say here's".